# ExpressJs res.sendFile doesn't work after middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to understand JWT and how they work with Node and Express .js. I have this middleware that tries to authenticate users with a token:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
 if(req.headers.cookie) {
var autenticazione = req.headers.cookie.toString().substring(10)
autenticazione = autenticazione.substring(0, autenticazione.length - 3)
console.log(autenticazione)
jwt.verify(autenticazione, app.get('superSegreto'), function(err) {
  if (err) {
    res.send('authentication failed!')
  } else {
  // if authentication works!
    next() } })
   } else {
    console.log('errore')} })
```

And this is the code for my protected url:

```
app.get('/miao', function (req, res) {

res.sendFile(__dirname + '/pubblica/inserisciutente.html')
res.end() })
```

Even though the path is correct (I even tried with path.join(__dirname + '/pubblica/inserisciutente.html) and got the same result), when visiting the url I just get a blank page (with even node conde inside) I also set:             app.use(express.static('/pubblica')) P.S. if I try to replace  res.sendFile(..) with res.send('Some stuff') I can correctly view it on the page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please indent your code properly.  Very hard to follow code that is improperly indented.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`res.sendFile()` is asynchronous and it will end its own response if it is successful.

So, when you call `res.end()` right after you start `res.sendFile()` you are ending the response before the code has actually sent the file.

You can do it like this:

```
app.get('/miao', function (req, res) {

    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/pubblica/inserisciutente.html', function(err) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(err.status).end();
        }
    });
});
```

See the Express doc for `res.sendFile()` [here](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.sendFile).

Comment: is if { } else { } else { } a valid conditional?

Comment: @ChrisL - if the OP would indent their code properly, you would see that it isn't actually `if { } else { } else { }`.    The last `else` is paired with an earlier `if`.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to end the response with `res.end()` then you must not mention or specify it after `res.sendFile()` because `res.sendFile()` is an asynchronous function that means it will take some time to execute and in that meantime next instruction which is in your case is `res.end()` will execute and that's why you didn't see any response send by the `res.sendFile`

You can visit the documentation to know more about `res.sendFile()` [visit documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile)